# Search a nested field for multiple values on the same field with elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to query a nested properties with multiple values.

Here is an example that will be clearer.

**Create an index with a nested field**

```
    curl -X DELETE "http://localhost:9200/testing_nested_query/"
    curl -X POST "http://localhost:9200/testing_nested_query/" -d '{
        "mappings": {
            "class": {
              properties: {
                title: {"type": "string"},
                "students": {
                  "type": "nested",
                  "properties": {
                    "name": {"type": "string"}
                  }
                }
              }
            }
        }

    }'
```

**Add some values**

```
    curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/testing_nested_query/class/1' -d '{
      "title": "class1",
      "students": [{"name": "john"},{"name": "jack"},{"name": "jim"}]
    }'

    curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/testing_nested_query/class/2' -d '{
      "title": "class2",
      "students": [{"name": "john"},{"name": "chris"},{"name": "alex"}]
    }'
```

**Query for all classes where john is (2 hits as expected)**

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/testing_nested_query/class/_search' -d '{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path":"students",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {"match": {"students.name": "john"}}
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

**Query for classes where both john and jack are attending ( 0 results instead of 1)**

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/testing_nested_query/class/_search' -d '{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path":"students",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {"match": {"students.name": "john"}},
            {"match": {"students.name": "jack"}}
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

I've tried with match and filter but I can never get the query to return the expected values.

Comment: The query would work simply by using "should" instead of "must".

Comment: No, with "should" It returns 2 hits instead of one.

Comment: You're right, I misread the question.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It just needs a bit change:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
        "must": [
           {
               "nested": {
                  "path":"students",
                  "query": {
                    "bool": {
                      "must": [
                        {"match": {"name": "john"}}
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                }
           },
           {
               "nested": {
                  "path":"students",
                  "query": {
                    "bool": {
                      "must": [
                        {"match": {"name": "jack"}}
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                }
           }
        ]
    }
  }
}
```

**Why?**

Basically, in a nested query, the query and the filter are collectively executed on a single nested document - in your case one name. So your query would pick up every nested document and try to find every document that has `name` equal to `john` and `jack` at the same time - which is impossible.

My query tries to find an indexed document that has one nested document with `name` equal to `john` and another nested document with `name` equal to `jack`. So basically one nested query tries to match one nested document completely.

To prove what I am suggesting, try this:

**Create the same index with same mapping as you did**

** Then index the following documents **

```
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/testing_nested_query/class/1' -d '{
      "title": "class1",
      "students": [{"name": "john", "age": 4},{"name": "jack", "age": 1},{"name": "jim", "age": 9}]
    }'

curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/testing_nested_query/class/2' -d '{
      "title": "class1",
      "students": [{"name": "john", "age": 5},{"name": "jack", "age": 4},{"name": "jim", "age": 9}]
    }'
```

**Now execute the following queries:**

```
{
  "query": {
       "nested": {
          "path":"students",
          "query": {
            "bool": {
              "must": [
                {"match": {"name": "john"}},
                {"match": {"age": 4}}
              ]
            }
          }
        }
  }
}
```

According to your expectations, this should match 2 documents but it actually matches just only one. Because there is only one nested document that has both `name` equal to `john` and `age` equal to `4`.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

You could also do following way. where you do not need to repeat bool again in a nested block , since there is a only one to match within that block , you can just do term match without bool

```js
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [{
        "nested": {
          "path": "students",
          "query": {
            {
              "term": {
                "name": "john"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }, {
        "nested": {
          "path": "students",
          "query": {
            {
              "term": {
                "name": "jack"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }]
    }
  }
}
```